# Solution to playing various strams in Asterisk

Tags: bash, asterisk, mplayer

We have a few radio stations that we stream on the phone. Most of them have their stream in MP3 format. Some are using MMS while others are using RTSP.

We have two issues:

1) Finding a solution for all common formatss. Currently only MP3 works with madplay. MMS requires mplayer which keeps dying.
2) Even when using madplay the boxes can only handle 20-30 different streams as each stream uses 2-3% of the CPU. Currently musiconhold.conf launches each bash script on start so if say we have 30 channels in we need to pull all of them regardless if anyone calls to listen.

Below are the two bash scripts that we use:

Madplay:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -q -T 120 -O - http://example.org/stream.mp3 | /usr/local/bin/madplay -Q -o raw:- --mono -R 8000 -a -6 -
```

Mplayer

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n "`ls /tmp/pdmohpipe`" ]; then
    rm -f /tmp/pdmohpipe
fi
PIPE="/tmp/pdmohpipe"
mknod $PIPE p
sleep 3
/usr/local/bin/mplayer mms://10.10.10.10/radio_online -really-quiet -quiet -ao pcm:nowaveheader,file=$PIPE -af resample=8000,channels=1,format=mulaw  | cat $PIPE
rm $PIPE
```

Perhaps using moh realtime would help as it would only get pulled if some one wants to listen to it? I know that FreeSwitch supports VLC, does anyone know if Asterisk has such support?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any solution which able change output to slin(8khz 16 bit uncompressed pcm)

You can use one hold thread per box per each moh class. For that need use

```
[general]
;cachertclasses=yes ; use 1 instance of moh class for all users who are using it,
                    ; decrease consumable cpu cycles and memory
                    ; disabled by default
```

Please note, that is GLOBAL settings of musiconhold module.
As result every new caller with same moh class will be connected to same(transcoded) moh classes via audiohooks,similar to conference. All will hear SAME moment of file/stream

Comment: Any suggestions on what would use less CPU than madplay? The issue is that if I have 50 streams, even if no one is listening it's still using the CPU.

Comment: 50 different streams?

Comment: Actually now the project is to play 150. Currently I have it spread across 3 VPS's.

Comment: If so, you have create system which will turn off unused stream and share same stream. Or setup transcode outside main asterisk box. Or write something that do better decompression then mpeg lib(which is not so easy,really)

Comment: arheops: Any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: Read "Asterisk the future of telephony " book. It is just metter of programming. You have kill unused streams, start streams before someone need listen it, etc.